# iOS Pass on label of row in UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to pass on the label of a table row when you hit that rows accessory button as it matches the key of an array in a plist, so the next page knows which array to load the settings from.

This is the code I'm using at the moment in `performSegueWithIdentifier`:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
SettingsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.nameViewer = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Unfortunately every time it picks the first row... I know because using `NSLog` it always gives the same output (the name of the first row). Any Ideas?

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you tap an accessory button of a cell, the cell itself doesn't get selected (this is normal behavior since accessory buttons fire a different delegate method), so you get always `0`.

What you could do though is to set an ivar with the selected index inside `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` delegate method and pass that ivar to your destination controller. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: I did - it made me wait for a bit first :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `-prepareForSegue:sender:` instead of `-prepareForSegue:` and use the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[[segue sourceViewController] tableView] indexPathForCell:sender];

    SettingsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    destViewController.nameViewer = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```